# How to pass maven options to JaCoCo tool in Maven@3 task in Azure Devops

Tags: java, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, jacoco

I am trying to build, run tests and publish JaCoCo code coverage reports using Azure Devops pipelines. I followed the documentation of the task provided in [link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops)

The final task which i am running is something like this:

```
- task: Maven@3
      displayName: Build Project
      inputs:
        mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
        goals: 'clean package'
        options: '-s settings.xml'
        publishJUnitResults: true,
        testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
        codeCoverageToolOption: 'jaCoCo'
        ....
```

This results tasks runs fails at the verify step. Below is the maven commands those get run:

1. `/usr/share/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn -version`
2. `/usr/share/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn -f /home/vsts/work/1/s/pom.xml help:effective-pom -s settings.xml`
3. `/usr/share/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn -f /home/vsts/work/1/s/pom.xml -s /home/vsts/work/_temp/settings.xml clean package` and finally
4. `/usr/share/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn -f /home/vsts/work/1/s/pom.xml verify` - **FAILS**

As you can see for step 2 and step 3 both have `-s settings.xml` in the command, but in case of step 4 (which is initiated by the JaCoCo part of the task), the option (`-s settings.xml`) is not passed because of which certain dependencies are not getting downloaded and the build is failing.

Can anyone provide me some insights as to how to propagate the maven args to the JaCoCo coverage `mvn verify` command. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is the `clean package` correct according to what you want to achieve?

Comment: yes, i want to clean the target folder and package the app into a jar.